# how to insert a url/variable into onclick?

Tags: javascript, variables, onclick

this can't be too complex but it is baffling me - I would like to pass a variable through a url (www.site.com/index.html?var=whatever.htm) and use the variable within an onclick function so that the onclick button uses the variable as the url to go to..onclick.

I am trying to do this in place of a history button, since the button is within a frame, and clicks to other frames change what the history actually is.

I tried `<input value="Go Back" onclick="parent.location(var)" type="button">`, but clearly i am missing something on how to get javascript to recognize that variable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171713/how-to-retrieve-query-string-parameter-and-values-using-javascript-jquery/1213338#1213338

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `document.location.search` to access the query string. Then you need to parse that string for the value of your variable.

In you onclick handler, you should set `document.location` to the value of your variable.

I would suggest adding your click handler when the page loads, as opposed to inlining it with your HTML element.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("go").onclick = function () {
        var tokens = /\bvar=([^&]+)/.exec(document.location.search);

        if (tokens) {
            document.location = decodeURIComponent(tokens[1]);
        }
    };
};
```

**Edit:** For a more generic mechanism for parsing the query string, try this: http://gist.github.com/143101

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using

parent.location **=** var ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var url = "http://gohere.com";
</script>
<input value="Go Back" onclick="document.location(url)" type="button" />
```

You could also have a general function that you call that has the "back" location already set, like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function goBack(url){
    document.location(url);
  }
</script>
```

In that case you would need to set the url variable somehow.  The idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Variable From URL:
  First of all there is no automated way accessing url parameters. So we need to split url into 3 groups.

```
http://www.someurl.com/doSomeThing?one=1&two=2
```

we need to get one = 1 and two = 2 parts. We can access this by regular expression.

```
  var regexString = "[\\?&]var=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexString );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
```

If the results is an array and first element will be your value.

```
window.location=results[1];
```

Regards,
Jishnu