# Grabbing a url variable from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript REGEX: How to get youtube video id from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url)

In javascript I need to grab a url variable that can be the first variable but doesn't have to. The url is a string of a url from Youtube. At first I was using regex to replace everything from & on, but then I found out that the video variable isn't always first. I am not good with regex and just have gone with tutorials I can find and double check to make sure it works right. So I need to be able to grab the `v=videoletters` part. If I can grab that, I think I can figure from then on to make the normal youtube url which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does exactly what you asked for:

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Found via a Google search on this page: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

So, you would just do:

```
var videoletters = gup("v");
```

There are many, many other ways to do this also that you can see via your own search.  Here are a few of the others:

[How to retrieve query string parameter and values using javascript (Jquery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171713/how-to-retrieve-query-string-parameter-and-values-using-javascript-jquery)

http://www.idealog.us/2006/06/javascript_to_p.html

http://stevenbenner.com/2010/03/javascript-regex-trick-parse-a-query-string-into-an-object/

http://geekswithblogs.net/PhubarBaz/archive/2011/11/21/getting-query-parameters-in-javascript.aspx