# Regular expression to find anchor link with special href?

Tags: c#, regex

I just need to find a regular expression for the following:

I have some content in `div` tag, that includes lot of anchor links in it. So my task is to find anchor links with `href` as format of "components/showdoc.aspx?docid=" And then add `onclick` event for that anchor link only, leave the rest of the anchor links.

```
<div id="content" runat="server">
    <a href="www.xxxx.com/components/showdoc.aspx?docid=100">test doc</a>
</div>
```

This expression gives and add target to it.

```
RegEx.Replace(inputString, "<(a)([^>]+)>", "<$1 target=""_blank""$2>")
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

The <center> cannot hold it is too late.

Comment: your onclick event is client-side, correct? would a javascript solution be acceptable?

Comment: I agree with @Zeus. I'd use jQuery to do this.

Comment: Ia mthinking to do it this way:$('a[href*="components/showdoc.aspx?docid="]').on('click', myClickFunction);   but my questions is how to access that document id in onclick function?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex to parse html, it's evil.

You could use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com), it even has a nice [NuGet Package](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack).

Alternatively, you could do this on the client side with a single line of jQuery:

```
$('a[href*="components/showdoc.aspx?docid="]').on('click', myClickFunction);
```

This is making use of the [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

If you want to find the docid in your click function, you could write something like this in your click function:

```
function myClickFunction(e){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var docId = href.split('=')[1];
    alert(docId);
}
```

Note that this assumes there's only ever one query string value, if you wanted to make this more robust you could do something like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1171731/21200

Comment: this makes sense, but is there any way to get the docid from that url and use it in onclick function?

Comment: @user1542851, I've updated my answer to show how you can get the href of the link you've clicked on, and then find the query string value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make permanent changes to your HTML file, first manage your HTML parsing by loading it into a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control. From there you can perform DOM-like modifications to the HTML without the dangerous repercussions of parsing corruption that can be caused by performing `Regex.Replace` on the raw file. (Apparently RegEx + HTML is a serious issue for some).

So first in your code you would:

```
WebBrowser myBrowser = new WebBrowser();
myBrowser.URL = @"C:\MyPath\MyFile.HTML";
HtmlElement myDocBody = myBrowser.Document.Body;
```

Then you can navigate through your document body, seeking out your `div` tag and looking for your anchor tags by using the `HtmlElement.Id` property and `HtmlElement.GetAttribute` method.

Note: feel free to still use RegEx matching on the URL strings but only after extracting them from a `GetAttribute("href")` method.

To add the `onClick` method, simply invoke the `HtmlElement.SetAttribute` method.

When you have finished all your modifications, save the changes by writing the `WebBrowser.DocumentText` to file.

Here is a reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx